# How do I make my Haskell functions available in my Python Flask app?

Tags: python, http, haskell, flask

I have a machine learning model written in Haskell, but want to use Python and Flask for the front end. How do I pass data to my Haskell function from within my Python Flask app? Some code examples would be helpful - I have looked at Servant so far, but don't know how that would work with a Flask app already in place.

Comment: You'll need to write another Web server in Haskell (WAI/Warp are good for this, and you can use a full framework like Yesod if you want something complicated), and make requests to it from your Flask application. (Which isn't really a "front end" in normal parlance, it runs on a server so is more "back end" - the front end of any web application has to be done in HTML and Javascript.)

Comment: Thanks! Trying to figure out how to run the Warp server now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a reasonably fast way to make a web-based interface for your machine learning model as FifthCode has suggested, you might want to consider [Scotty](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty). It's a Sinatra-inspired web framework for Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty

import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main = scotty 3000 $
    get "/:word" $ do
        beam <- param "word"
        html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

Notably, a call using a REST API like this will block. Depending on how long it takes your machine learning model to run, you may want to use a a webhook approach where you submit a job with HTTP/HTTPS and include a webhook URL on your flask app that the Scotty app will POST to when it has finished running the model.

When your Flask app POSTs to /predict on the Scotty app it will end up blocking until the Scotty app responds. Having the Scotty app spawn a thread for the ML work, respond with 204 Accepted immediately after, and then the ML thread POSTs to /prediction on the Flask app with the result when it completes.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using Scotty. In my Flask app, I post to `localhost:5000/predict`. Then in my Scotty app, I have `server = scotty 5000 $ do post "/predict" $ do ....` Is this what you mean by web hook approach? My Scotty app is waiting for a response from the Flask app, after which it will act on what it receives.

Comment: Good point. Not quite. I've clarified the webhook approach in my answer.